# Magento2: How product per page option working?

Tags: magento-2.2.5, toolbar

Issue:

Can any explain me regarding how the url is created on change of product per page option in magento2. You can check in image on change of limit the value is binded to url I want to know regarding working and creation of url.

[image]

Is there any solution to change url as per given requirement

Answer (score 0):

`product_list_limit` will change in URL once you change item per page from right bottom drop-down.

It's value of that drop-down. As per your attached image its working fine.

To Test it change drop-down value from 30 to 15. it will update in URL.